# Adding check constraints without "create assertion" in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I'm trying to add a check constraint to the tables ORDERS and RESULTS in my database, but MYSQL won't accept assertions. How do I edit this to fit MYSQL's accepted syntax? Can it be done with an ALTER TABLE?

```
CREATE ASSERTION
CHECK (NOT EXISTS SELECT * FROM ORDERS, RESULTS, 
WHERE ORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER = RESULTS.ORDER_NUMBER 
AND ORDERS.ORDER_DATE > RESULTS.DATE_REPORTED);
```

Comment: MySQL neither supports assertion (no DBMS does) nor check constraints

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support check constraints, so they will be ignored. look at [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-data-definition.html) to see the allowed syntaxes. You can try using a trigger instead to check the inserted data at insert/update time!